# Integrate R with NodeJS

Tags: r, node.js, math, integrate

I'm new in Node and I'm searching for a way to integrate Node js with the R compiler. How can i run a R script in Node or maybe compile it with R and then get the result ? Thanks

I need something like this

```js
...

// i need to compile and get the result of a R file like this
// the R script returns a number between 0 and 100
var exp = compileRFile(" **file location** ");

if (exp <= 0.1){
    console.log(`your exp ${exp} is lower than 0.1`);
}else {

...
```

Comment: Can you add a reproducible example?

Comment: i added an example

Comment: You're probably looking for this: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using the "r-integration" package. This library allows you to execute arbitrary R commands or scripts(files) from the Node JS environment by using system calls.

To install it in your Node JS project just run
npm install r-integration

You can find more info about it here:
[r-integration](https://www.npmjs.com/package/r-integration)

Comment: [r-script](https://github.com/fridgerator/r-script) is also a good package

Comment: "using system calls" -- it spawns a shell and then runs R.